# Hibernate: two datasources to initialise single object

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, datasource

I have two separate db schemas (or 2 users' tables in Oracle's jargon) - schemaA and schemaB.

schemaA, among other tables, has table:

`domain(id NUMBER PK, description(VARCHAR2(10))`

schemaB has table:

`q_user(id NUMBER PK, username VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL, domain_id NUMBER, CONSTRAINT foreign key references schemaA.domain(id))`

Java class QUser has the following properties: 
`Long id,
String username, 
Domain domain`

The question: is it possible to configure Hibernate to initialise QUser object using two different data sources (schemaA and schemaB)? If so, how do I do it?

Also I'm using Spring 3, Hibernate 3.6 and Oracle 10g.

I came across Spring techniques to define multiple data sources and swap them dynamically, but I'm not sure that this can be used to initialise a single object.

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your domain mapping, you can enter the schema name also.

With XML:

```
<class name="Domain" table="domain" catalog="schemaA">
```

With annotations:

```
@Table(name = "domain", schema = "schemaA")
```

Then, you don't need multiple datasources. You set up a *single* datasource that connects using **schemaB** user (since in the **schemaB** table you have permission to access the **schemaA** table - hence the foreign key).

Comment: Thanks! This looks good, but in order to keep the question clean I kept the relation Domain to User as 1 to 1, but in real life I have many-to-many. So, I have this intersection table in the middle user_domain (user_id NUMBER, domain_id NUMBER). When I try adding schema (or catalog) to Domain model class I get - no such table or view error. When I look at the generated sql it does not apply the schema to the Domain in the "... from Domain ..." (should be schemaA.Domain). I guess this many-to-many relation is a different case - can you point me in the right direction here please? many thank

Comment: @damo_inc Are you using XML or annotations? I re-checked and there is a schema attribute also in XML.

Comment: I'm using annotations. I managed to fix it by creating synonyms on the other schema's tables. Fortunately I have full sys access to both schemas :). Many thanks for your help.